# Banana Pi Static IP

Tags: linux, ip, router, banana-pi

I have a BananaPi running with Linux as my NAS. 
It is running really perfect for me. Now, I want to configure to connect it from the internet.

But, when i try to give the device a static IP address, router gave the following error message

> This device is a broadcasting device and cannot have a static IP address

Does anybody know how I can avoid this problem so that my NAS has a static IP ?

I don't want to turn DHCP in my network off because I have a huge amount of devices connected and I don't want to manage all my addresses manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your network you can keep running a DHCP server. But if you like to set an static IP to an device, you have to disable the DHCP client on the device.

Take a look at `/etc/network`.

Or look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/327412/is-there-a-safe-way-to-disable-dhcp-from-command-line

Btw. Stackoverflow is not the right platform to ask admininstration-specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked fine for me.
Sry for the post here, i hoped that here are some linux experts.